# Marking a question as duplicate: Should we consider question creation time or score?

Tags: discussion

I have seen two questions, which are duplicate of each other.

Question 1: Posted seven years back and the user has been removed:

*[calling thread.start() within its own constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84285/calling-thread-start-within-its-own-constructor)*

Question score: 8

Answer score: 13

Question 2: Posted five years back

[Why not to start a thread in the constructor? How to terminate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623285/why-not-to-start-a-thread-in-the-constructor-how-to-terminate)

Question score: 32

Answer score: 29

Question 3 (posted 4 years back):

*[Java: starting a new thread in a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8057510/java-starting-a-new-thread-in-a-constructor)*

Question score: 16

Answer score: 22

I would like to mark Question 1 & Question 3 as a duplicate of Question 2, but Question 1 has been created before Question 2.

One of these questions should be marked as a duplicate. What would be the criteria to mark a duplicate?

Is it question-creation time? Is it popularity of the post?

Comment: You should consider the quality of the answers, first and foremost. Failing that, the quality of the question. This is a duplicate itself, as it's come up before.

Comment: @Tunaki, I have seen your pro-active contribution in marking duplicate questions on daily basis. If I try to close the question, it requires 5 votes but if you close duplicate question, your single vote should suffice. Can you please check all three questions and mark it as duplicate?

Comment: I took a quick look but can't read them all carefully now. To me, [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8057510/java-starting-a-new-thread-in-a-constructor) looks like the best of the three (clear, direct and simple). Q2 is awkward since there are 2 unrelated questions asked... There may be another one out there.

Comment: The second one has one more sub-question: How to terminate and that one has more votes for both question and answer

Comment: OK, I couldn't find a better one so I went ahead and closed a bunch of duplicates to target Q3 ([this is the search I used](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+start+thread+constructor+is%3Aq)). Still unsure about Q2 because of the second question that all answer addresses.

Comment: On a different note: java interface abstract class - You can find many duplicates with little difference in question in most of them : http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=java%20interface%20abstract%20class%20is%3aQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The factors that I take into account when closing as duplicate:

1. Question quality. (Better asked, better explained, etc.)
2. Answers(s) quality, as measured by the score.

Time is not really a factor, I have no problem closing an old question as a duplicate of a newer question that was asked better and/or got better answers.